# ModbusTCP: Reverse engineering without having any documents of client(master)

Tags: server, reverse-engineering, simulator, modbus, pymodbus3

**Concept**

we have a ship simulator(client) and Modbus controller(Server). **Our goal is to develop an emulator(like controller)** on my PC. But we have no information about the client(simulator).

**Progress**

- Firstly we checked the actual outputs from the controller(server). There are 7 different variables like engine telegraph, rudder angle and so no.
- Secondly, I checked the register numbers of the controller, which store command values. **It was from 0 to 7.**

Polling server with Modpoll software installed server:

[image: screen1]

- I checked the register type. It was a holding register
- I wrote a script to develop a Server like a controller with pymodbus Server. I can not only write specific values on the holding register from 0 to 7, but also there are proper handshake and responses to the simulator(client)

**Problem**

- **Client sends a request for reading with register numbers from 256**. **It means that my Server responds with zero values not with the command values written on the registers from 0 to 7.** But the problem is that the simulator(client) shows the changes of the parameters on its Graphical user interface.

Screen shot from wireshark - it shows that clinet(simulator) sends a request with register nuumber from 246:

[image: screen2]

- Client sends a request not only for reading but also for writing and the writing request overwrite the values written by Server (PC).

**Question**

1. **how is it possible that the simulator receives the command signal by requesting different register numbers? client must send a request with register numbers from 0 to receive command signals.**
2. **I cannot understand why the client writes first before reading values from Server.** This read request overwrites the values written by Server (pc). The Server (controller or pc) is to send a command signal to the simulator. I have no idea why the simulator first writes some values on sever and read it.

Please advise on this issue.

Best regards
Byeon seongsu.